# Stopwatch service for updating notification

Tags: android

I am working on time tracking app. I need to track time and display it in activity and notification in minutes and seconds live. In order to display live time in notification I need some kind of service that updates the notification each second eventually sends broadcast for updating the stopwatch in activity. The question is how to implement the service.

Should I use something like `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`/`ACTION_SCREEN_ON` to start and stop the service? What kind of timer should I use for example `JobScheduler`?

Thank you all for any response :)

Comment: Try sticky notification like ongoing notification or use forground service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually discovered that I dont need a service to update the notification. I can use `Chronometer` widget that does all the magic with counting seconds.